# How to Count number of text instances in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a table of my workdays and I want to count instances of word 'work' in each row.
I have a table like this:
[image: Simple Work Sheet]

I used this code in J1 cell but it doesn't work.

```
=SUM(IF(2:2 = "Sleep",1,0))
```

I have found this formula in microsoft's website but it doesn't work.
What is causing this problem?

Comment: Do you  want the count of "Sleep"? If yes then put this in `J2`... `=COUNTIF(C2:I2,"Sleep")`

Comment: Yes! I want count string like "Sleep" in cells

Comment: I have posted the formula above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `COUNTIF` function.

```
=COUNTIF(C2:I2,"Sleep")
```

This goes in Cell `J2`

**From Excel's Help**

> The COUNTIF function counts the number of cells within a range that meet a single criterion that you specify. For example, you can count all the cells that start with a certain letter, or you can count all the cells that contain a number that is larger or smaller than a number you specify.

When in doubt, press the magic button `F1` in Excel. :)

Comment: just FYI, if you use Excel in a different language the command might be different @see: http://en.excel-translator.de/countif/

Answer (score 0):

Just came across a similar thing in a worksheet and came to google before I remembered why it didn't work.

The countif statement above is perfectly fine, however the original formula given wouldn't have worked as to use a sum in this way means you have to make it an array or CSE Formula instead.

So, if you come across this, click in the formula bar and press ctrl + shift + enter and it should sort the whole thing out.